# What's the word that describes the strenuousness of an animal untenably struggling to help itself?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Which word or phrase could be used in these sentences?

> Look at that cockroach helplessly _______ to flip itself back onto its legs.

Or

> The battle is over. The deer cannot escape the lion’s jaws anymore, yet it still ______.

The word needs not imply inevitable death, but it should describe a doomed struggle to help or save itself, and how strenuous and arduous this struggle is.

Comment: The title of this question is quite incomprehensible. What were you trying to say?

Comment: I just fix it. Is it better?

Comment: I **think** I understand what you mean now. I’ve edited both the title and the question according to how I understand it; please feel free to change it if I’ve misunderstood.

Comment: Thank you. In your edit, is "a doomed struggle" a complete noun phrase? Or should *struggle* be understood as the verb of *a doomed (one)*?

Comment: It's a noun phrase. It is the struggle that is doomed (to fail).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word that immediately comes to my mind is [flail](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flail).

> :  to move, swing, or beat like a flail *arms flailing in the water*

This is a word that refers more to the movement of the object, rather than its goal, but I think is very appropriate for the sentences you give.

> Look at how that cockroach helplessly **flails (in an attempt)** to flip itself
>
> The battle has come to the end. The deer obviously cannot escape the lion's jaw anymore, yet it still **flails**.

Answer (score 5):

Another choice is ***thrash***.  [Collins dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/thrash) meaning #3:

> [To] move in a wild or violent way, often hitting against something. You can also say that someone's arms or legs *thrash* about.
>
> - Many of the crew died a terrible death as they *thrashed* about in shark-infested waters.
> - ...dreams so vivid that I *thrash* inside my sleeping bag and cry out.
> - Jimmy collapsed on the floor, *thrashing* his legs about like an injured racehorse.

Comment: Does *thrash* have an connotation of hitting something?

Comment: @Ooker One of the meanings of thrash is to beat but it doesn't necessarily mean that.  In the examples given above there's no connotation of hitting.

Answer (score 3):

[Toil](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/toil) comes to mind:

> **Toil** (verb)
>
> 1 Work extremely hard or incessantly.
>       *‘we toiled away’*
>       (with infinitive)
>       *‘Richard toiled to build his editorial team’*
>
> 1.1 (with adverbial of direction) Move slowly and with difficulty.
>       *‘she began to toil up the cliff path’*

However, I'm finding it hard to think of a single word that fits in both your example sentences. In both cases, you have already adequately described the hopelessness of the situation ("helplessly"/"obviously cannot escape"); so it seems redundant to again stress the helplessness by your choice of verb.

I would have used the following:

> Look at how that cockroach helplessly **trying** to flip itself
>
> The battle has come to the end. The deer obviously cannot escape the lion's jaw anymore, yet it still **tries/puts up a fight**.

Answer (score 1):

The word that jumps out to me is ***tries***:

> ***[try](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/try)***
>
> VERB
>
> 1. *[no object]* Make an attempt or effort to do something.
>      *[with infinitive]* *‘he tried to regain his breath’*
>      *‘I started to try and untangle the mystery’*
>      *‘I decided to try writing fiction’*
>      *[with object]* *‘three times he tried the manoeuvre and three times he failed’*

So your example sentences would be:

> Look at how that cockroach helplessly ***tries*** to flip itself

and

> The battle has come to the end. The deer obviously cannot escape the lion's jaw anymore, yet it still ***tries***.

Alternately, as suggested in your question, you could use ***struggles***:

> ***[struggle](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/struggle)***
>
> VERB
>
> [NO OBJECT]
>
> 1. Make forceful or violent efforts to get free of restraint or constriction.
>      *‘before she could struggle, he lifted her up’*
>      *[with infinitive] ‘he struggled to break free’*

so your sentences would be:

> Look at how that cockroach helplessly ***struggles*** to flip itself

and

> The battle has come to the end. The deer obviously cannot escape the lion's jaw anymore, yet it still ***struggles***.